# Bones parented, but do not move mesh in pose mode?

Tags: mesh, bones, pose-mode

Try as I might, I just cannot figure out a solution to this! I have looked far and wide but thus far nothing has worked...

[image]

The skeleton has been parented and I'm able to move the mesh around when selecting the bones in Object mode, but when in Pose mode, it's as if the bones are not attached, as the mesh doesn't move at all?

[image]

This model is for a mod I've been working on, and I was planning to use the skeleton/animations already available in the game but with a new model, so some of the bones are left floating (though some, like the hands just haven't been moved into place yet). I would remove said floating bones, but I wouldn't be able to retarget the premade animations correctly later on...as far as I know.

I'm fairly new to blender, so admittedly, I'm not so sure what I am doing wrong here. I know this sort of thing is possible as I have seen other mods that have done the same thing before.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome. can u attach a simplified blend file repriducing the same behavior. https://blend-exchange.com